# Linux xml parse

Tags: xml, linux, xml-parsing, xmllint

I am trying to parse a portion of an xml file using xmllint but I cannot get it to work.

Here is the part I am interested in:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S2SCTIcf:SCTIcfBlkCredTrf xmlns:S2SCTIcf="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf SCTIcfBlkCredTrf.xsd">
  <S2SCTIcf:SndgInst>AAAAAAAA</S2SCTIcf:SndgInst>
  <S2SCTIcf:RcvgInst>BBBBBBBB</S2SCTIcf:RcvgInst>
  <S2SCTIcf:FileRef>ISCT181127000006</S2SCTIcf:FileRef>
  <S2SCTIcf:SrvcId>SCT</S2SCTIcf:SrvcId>
  <S2SCTIcf:TstCode>T</S2SCTIcf:TstCode>
  <S2SCTIcf:FType>ICF</S2SCTIcf:FType>
  <S2SCTIcf:FDtTm>2018-11-27T17:01:41.198+00:00</S2SCTIcf:FDtTm>
  <S2SCTIcf:NumCTBlk>1</S2SCTIcf:NumCTBlk>
  <S2SCTIcf:NumPCRBlk>0</S2SCTIcf:NumPCRBlk>
  <S2SCTIcf:NumRFRBlk>0</S2SCTIcf:NumRFRBlk>
  <S2SCTIcf:NumROIBlk>0</S2SCTIcf:NumROIBlk>
  <S2SCTIcf:NumSRBlk>0</S2SCTIcf:NumSRBlk>
  <S2SCTIcf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
```

Is there a way to get the value from tag `<S2SCTIcf:FDtTm>` for example? Should I escape the `:` sign?

Comment: I see an XML snippet, but not what you tried or in which way it failed? As it stands this is off-topic...

Comment: I've tried the command `xmllint --shell file.xml <<< "cat //S2SCTIcf:FDtTm/text()"
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
//S2SCTIcf:FDtTm/text(): no such node
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff before a colon is a name space prefix. You need to register the namespace and use it in the XPath expressions:

```
setns s=urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf
cat //s:FDtTm/text()
```

So, the whole script can be something like

```
#!/bin/bash

ext=$(cat <<'EOF'                    \
          | xmllint --shell file.xml \
          | grep -A1 -- '-------'    \
          | tail -n1
setns s=urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf
cat //s:FileRef/text()
EOF
)
echo "$ext"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution. Is there a way to store the output of the following command into a bash variable? `xmllint --shell filename | awk 'FNR==2 { print $0 }' | cut -c 1-1`. I was trying like so `#!/usr/bin/bash
#set -x
echo 'setns s=urn:S2SCTCvf:xsd:$SCTCvfBlkCredTrf
      cat //s:FileRef/text()' | \
ext=$(xmllint --shell filename | awk 'FNR==2 { print $0 }' | cut -c 1-1)
echo $ext` but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: Why your solution didn't work: commands in a pipeline are executed in a subshell. Changes in variable values aren't propagated from subshells to parent shells.